# Python. How to fix error: "print tablecsv.read() AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read"

Tags: python, csv

I lern Python and try to do parcer for html table and then I wont to create .csv file for import data into mySQL.

```
>>> htmlread = handlestatbydate.read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(htmlread))
>>> souptable = soup('tbody', limit=2)[1].findAll('tr')
>>> souptablestr = ''.join(str(t) for t in souptable)
>>> reclearbyonce = re.compile('</tr><tr>\n|^<tr>\n|</tr>$')
>>> recleartd = re.compile(r'</td>|<td.*?>')
>>> retdtd = re.compile('""| ')
>>> soupclearbyonce = reclearbyonce.sub('', souptablestr)
>>> soupcleartd = recleartd.sub('"', soupclearbyonce)
>>> souptdtd = retdtd.sub('","', soupcleartd)
>>> print souptdtd
"59","00059413","00059413","70000000001","2011-08-22","18:01:48","0:07","0.45"
"60","00059413","00059413","70000000002","2011-08-22","18:49:48","0:43","1.95"
"61","00059413","00059413","70000000003","2011-08-22","18:52:50","5:07","11.70"
"62","00059413","00059413","70000000003","2011-08-22","19:02:47","4:10","9.75"
```

Then, I create csv file and have error.

```
>>> tablecsv = file(r'/tmp/table.csv', 'w')
>>> tablecsv.write("".join(souptdtd))
>>> tablecsv = (r'/tmp/table.csv', 'r')
>>> print tablecsv.read()

    print tablecsv.read()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read
```

Unfortunately, I can't understad when and how I can create tuple. Could somebody explain me when I wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Omg... shure.  I should go to sleep, stupid error =) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the method name here: `tablecsv = (r'/tmp/table.csv', 'r')` i.e. you probably want to open the file .e.g `tablecsv = open(r'/tmp/table.csv', 'r')`

You should also close the file after writing before reading from it with `tablecsv.close()`

If you just have a list of items in brackets e.g. `(r'/tmp/table.csv', 'r')` then this creates a tuple.